# jQuery Loop and Print/Update Array with .each loop

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, each

I'm have a a dilemna, as listed below:

My code needs to simply find current select options that are selected, by use of a loop and create an array (and also print) with jQuery.

Here is my HTML:

```
        <input id="customSKU" name="" value="Test" style="width: 100%; padding: 5px 0px;" type="textarea">

        <div class="product-fields">
                <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Case &amp; Clip</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a case and clip for your product.</span></p>
        <p>         <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[0][27]" id="customPrice027"><option value="55">Select Case &amp; Clip</option><option value="56">Black - Large - $25.00 - 1</option><option value="57">Black - None -  - 2</option><option value="58">Beige - Small - $10.00 - 3</option><option value="98">Beige - Large - $20.00 - 4</option><option value="99">Beige - None -  - 5</option><option value="100">Blue - Small - $10.00 - 6</option><option value="101">Blue - Large - $20.00 - 7</option><option value="102">Blue - None -  - 8</option><option value="103">Gray - Small - $10.00 - 9</option><option value="104">Gray - Large - $20.00 - A</option><option value="105">Gray - None -  - B</option><option value="106">Red - Large - $20.00 - R</option><option value="107">Olive Drab - Large - $20.00 - D</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>
                    <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Switch Configuration</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a switch configuration for your product.</span></p>
        <p>         <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[1][28]" id="customPrice128"><option value="60">Select Switch Configuration</option><option value="61">mom-mom0</option><option value="62">mom-lock (on) -  - 1</option><option value="63">PTT - $20.00 - 3</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>
                    <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Jack</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a jack for your product.</span></p>
        <p>         <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[2][29]" id="customPrice229"><option value="64">Select Jack</option><option value="65">TJT-120 (civil helo) - $10.00 - none</option><option value="66">TJT-101 (civil helo) - $30.00 - TJ</option><option value="67">TJT-120 (military) - $10.00 - W</option><option value="68">TJ-101 (military) - $30.00 - TJW</option><option value="69">TJT-125 (5 contacts) - $20.00 - B</option><option value="70">NATO (Europe) - $25.00 - N</option><option value="71">CIJ-051 (comm’l av’n) - $10.00 - C</option><option value="72">U-61/U (USFS) - $35.00 - F</option><option value="73">CIJ-055 &amp; CIJ-068 (general aviation) - $35.00 - G</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>
                    <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Volume Control</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a volume control for your product.</span></p>
        <p>         <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[3][30]" id="customPrice330"><option value="74">Select Volume Control</option><option value="75">No Impedance -  - none</option><option value="76">High Impedance - Grounded - $25.00 - H</option><option value="77">High Impedance - Not Grounded - $25.00 - HA</option><option value="78">Low Impedance - Grounded - $25.00 - L</option><option value="79">Low Impedance - Not Grounded - $25.00 - LA</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>
                    <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Cable &amp; Length</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a Cable and Length for your product.</span></p>
        <p><span class="editlinktip hasTip" title="Cable &amp; Length::**special coil cable for EMS applications, 20” straight section from end of cable to switch case" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;"><img src="/new/includes/js/ThemeOffice/tooltip.png" alt="Tooltip" border="0"></span>           <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[4][31]" id="customPrice431"><option value="80">Select Cable &amp; Length</option><option value="81">2 ft coil - $20.00 - K2</option><option value="82">3 ft** - $25.00 - KM</option><option value="83">3 ft coil - $25.00 - k3</option><option value="84">6 ft coil - $30.00 - K6</option><option value="85">10 ft coil - $40.00 - K10</option><option value="86">15 ft coil - $60.00 - K15</option><option value="87">20 ft coil - $80.00 - K20</option><option value="88">XXft str’t - $2.00 - /XX</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>
                    <div class="product-field product-field-type-V">
        <p><span class="product-fields-title"><b>Plug</b></span><br>
        <span class="product-field-desc">Choose a plug for your product.</span></p>
        <p><span class="editlinktip hasTip" title="Plug::*** especially wired for ANR" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333;"><img src="/new/includes/js/ThemeOffice/tooltip.png" alt="Tooltip" border="0"></span>         <span class="product-field-display"><select name="customPrice[5][32]" id="customPrice532"><option value="89">Select Plug</option><option value="90">TP-120 (civil helo) - $20.00 - 74</option><option value="91">TP-120 (military) - $20.00 - 74M</option><option value="92">U-75/U (USFS) - $40.00 - 75</option><option value="93">NATO (Europe) - $30.00 - NP</option><option value="94">U-384/U (5 contacts) - $30.00 - 84</option><option value="95">CIPC-055B &amp; CIPC-068 (gen’l av’n) - $35.00 - YP</option><option value="96">Lugs - $6.00 - 4L</option><option value="97">no plug -  - 4X</option></select></span></p>


        </div><br>


    </div>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function( index ) {
        console.log($( this ).text() );
    });
```

});

This will print a list in console, per each time this runs through the loop

Selected Option 1

Selected Option 2

Selected Option 3

Selected Option 4

Selected Option 5

Selected Option 6

What I need this to do, is update the top input box and append the value to be in order by select box, and have a space dash space between the entries.

Here is a link to jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vf3ry/2/

### EDIT:::

My original code, which parsed the last portion (after the last dash) and pulled only that value:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#customPrice027").change(function(){
        var selectedValues = $('#customPrice027').val();
        var selectedOption = $( "#customPrice027 option:selected" ).text();     

        selectedOption1 = selectedOption.substring(selectedOption.lastIndexOf("-"))
        $('#customSKU').val(selectedOption1);
    });
```

This code was my test, on my first select box before I used the loop method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .map() and Array.join()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        var vals = $("select option:selected").map(function (index) {
            return $.trim($(this).text())
        }).get();

        $('#customSKU').val(vals.join(' - '))
    }).first().change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/79r3s/)

Comment: Now lets say I want this to update per change event on select box, and clear, and re-create the updated fields?

Comment: This worked by the way. Thanks! Now I have some minor changes (like excluding default fields from showing, and also parsing this to get last value after checkbox. This is essentially building a SKU number, the last value in the options is the SKU number added by the select box.

Comment: @JustinBevan see the update.. if you want to exclude a value inside the map function return undefined for that value

Comment: I believe this does this for me. I shouldn't have a problem trimming this value, to get everything after the last dash. Thank you for your time good sir!

Comment: Alright, this is implemented in the site I am working on, but there is one issue. I previously had a function on change that would parse this correctly. Reference the function in my edited code. This parsed using Javascript, to get the last value after the dash, and ONLY print that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured this out actually, by using my Javascript to parse each value as needed. Thanks for your help!